# Xcode 4 embedded resource prevention

Tags: iphone, resources, xcode4

In XCode4, is there a way to have a 'resource' (i.e. a CSV used to load a sqlite database) that is there for project purposes, but not have it compiled into my project?  So my final app doesn't include it?  I can't seem to see to to have this facility.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you do not want the file get into your .app file, One solution i can think of is, do not include 'Target' when adding the file to the project. If you want to exclude your already added file then

1. Choose the target
2. Go to Build phases
3. Expand copy bundle resources
4. Select your resource file and remove it.

Comment: Thanks...done that but note that my csv files are still being included as part of my package contents.

Any clue?